# Abort download if file too large in Scala

Tags: scala, playframework

I am trying to download a file using the Scala APIs, but I would like it to abort if that file is too large (50MB).

I have managed to put together a very inefficient way that works for small files (< 10KB) but runs my CPU through the roof for large files:

```
var size = 0
val bytes = scala.io.Source.fromURL(url)(scala.io.Codec.ISO8859).toStream.map {
  c =>
    size = size + 1
    if (size > (maxMbSize*1024*1024)) {
      throw new Exception(s"File size is greater than the maximum allowed size of $maxMbSize MB")
    }
    c.toByte
}.toArray
```

I would like to be able to do this check more efficiently and also avoid the use of the `var` for the size. Is this possible?

Also I am using the play framework in case anyone knows of an API within that framework that may do what I am looking for.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your var here.

Comment: What are you looking to do with the file ultimately? Save it to file? Serve it to a client?

Comment: No I don't need to save the file. I am ultimately only going to calculate a SHA-1 checksum on the data and save only the checksum value

Comment: @LimbSoup I am trying to avoid downloading the entire file if it is too large and only calculate the checksum if it is within the file size limits that I set.

Comment: How does the snippet fail -- does it throw an `OutOfMemoryError`? How large are the large files?

Comment: It is possible to calculate a checksum without downloading the whole file in memory, you can download chunks, update your digest with each chunk and finally generate the hash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to load the data into a byte array at all - you can generate the hash on-the-fly with a `DigestInputStream` using existing Java libraries. In this example I am loading the data from a String, but you can adapt to load from a URL. We use a tail-recursive function to eliminate the `var`, and return an `Option` so that we can indicate a over-size file by returning `None`.

```
import java.io._
import java.security._
import scala.annotation.tailrec

def calculateHash(algorithm: MessageDigest, in: String, limit: Int): Option[Array[Byte]] = {

  val input = new ByteArrayInputStream(in.getBytes())
  val dis = new DigestInputStream(input, algorithm)

  @tailrec
  def read(total: Int): Option[Array[Byte]] = {
    if (total > limit) None
    else {
      val byte = dis.read()
      if (byte == -1) Some(algorithm.digest())
      else read(total + 1)
    }
  }
  read(0)
}
```

Example usage:

```
val sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1") 

calculateHash(sha1, "Hello", 5).get             

//> res0: Array[Byte] = Array(-9, -1, -98, -117, 123, -78, -32, -101, 112, -109, 90, 93, 120, 94, 12, -59, -39, -48, -85, -16)

calculateHash(sha1, "Too long!!!", 5)           

//> res1: Option[Array[Byte]] = None
```

You may also be able to get better performance by using the variant of `DigestInputStream.read()` that uses a buffer:

```
...
val buffer = new Array[Byte](1024)

@tailrec
def read(total: Int): Option[Array[Byte]] = {
  if (total > limit) None
  else {
    val count = dis.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length)
    if (count == -1) Some(algorithm.digest())
    else read(total + count)
  }
}
....
```

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly. I did something similar with recursion earlier but not with the DigestInputStream. That makes a big improvement on the speed of this code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are materializing all the data into memory, you don't really need to buffer it in small chunks (which is what the scala io library is doing).  Also since you want the bytes anyway, you don't need to be decoding the bytes into Char's only to reverse the process.

To lose your size var, you can make use of the zipWithIndex function, which pairs each element with it's index.  Do note that it starts at 0, so you need the + 1.

```
def readMyURL(url: String): Array[Byte] = {
    val is = new java.net.URL(url).openStream()
    val byteArray = Iterator.continually(is.read).zipWithIndex.takeWhile{
        zb =>
            if (zb._2 > (maxMbSize*1024*1024) + 1) {
                throw new Exception(s"File size is greater than the maximum allowed size of $maxMbSize MB")
            }
            -1 != zb._1  // -1 is the end of stream
    }.map(_._1.toByte).toArray
    is.close()
    byteArray
}
```

This is lazy, so the iterator will not traverse until you call toArray.

You may be able to get away with not closing that URL InputStream (it appears the scala io library does not do it).